# Derivative (Jacobian) of a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, matrix-calculus, kronecker-product

I have this equation:

$y = e^{t(A + W)} x_0 $

where A is a diagonal matrix and W is a symmetric matrix.

I need to find $\frac{\partial y}{\partial W}$.

If A and W commute then I could use the fact that

$e^{t(A + W)}  = e^{tA} . e^{tW}   $ and then use the kronecker product:

$\frac{\partial y}{\partial W} = x_0^T \otimes e^{tA} \, \,   vec(t e^{tW}) $

But I can't derive the case were they don't commute.

Any thoughts??
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\k{\otimes}  \def\h{\odot}
\def\BR#1{\Big[#1\Big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\Diag#1{\op{Diag}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\l{\lambda}   \def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\R{{\large\cal R}}
\def\x{x_0}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\J{{\cal J}}
$Construct a new *symmetric* matrix variable and calculate its eigendecomposition
$$\eqalign{
S &= \LR{A+W} &\qiq dS=dW \quad \{ \c{\sf\,differential\,} \} \\
S &= QLQ^T&\qiq I=Q^TQ,\;\;L=\Diag{\l_k} \\
}$$
Given a differentiable function $f,\,$
the $\sf Daleckii$ - $\sf Krein\ Theorem$
says
$$\eqalign{
F &= f(S) \\
dF &= Q\,\BR{R\h\LR{Q^TdS\,Q}}\,Q^T \\
{R_{jk}} &= \begin{cases}
{\large\frac{f(\l_j)-f(\l_k)}{\l_j-\l_k}} \qquad {\rm if}\;\l_j\ne\l_k \\
\\
\quad f'(\l_k) \qquad\quad\; {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}
}$$
where $\h$ denotes the Hadamard product.

In the current problem, the function is pretty simple
$$ f(\l)=e^{t\l},\qquad\quad f'(\l)=te^{t\l} $$
Use this to calculate the Jacobian $(\J)$ of $y$
$$\eqalign{
\def\J{{\cal J}}
y &= F\x \\
dy &= dF\,\x \\
 &= Q\BR{R\h\LR{Q^TdS\,Q}}Q^T\x \\
 &= \vc{Q\BR{R\h\LR{Q^TdW\,Q}}Q^T\x} \\
 &= \LR{\x^TQ\k Q}\cdot\c{\Diag{\vc{R}}}\cdot\vc{Q^TdW\,Q} \\
 &= \LR{\x^TQ\k Q}\cdot\c\R\cdot\LR{Q\k Q}^T\vc{dW} \\
\grad{y}{\vc W}
 &= \LR{\x\k I}^T\LR{Q\k Q}\,\R\;\LR{Q\k Q}^T \;\equiv\; \J \\
}$$
Without [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)#Compatibility_with_Kronecker_products) the gradient is a third-order tensor,
which cannot be expressed in matrix notation.

### Update

Since $y$ is a vector, you cannot optimize against it. So I'll assume that you are optimizing against a cost function such as
$\phi = \tfrac12 y^Ty$

Use the preceding results to calculate the gradient $(G)$ of this cost function
$$\eqalign{
d\phi &= y^Tdy \\
 &= F\x:dy \\
 &= F\x:\LR{Q\BR{R\h\LR{Q^TdW\,Q}}Q^T\x} \\
 &= \LR{Q^TF\x\x^TQ}:\BR{R\h\LR{Q^TdW\,Q}} \\
 &= Q\BR{R\h Q^TF\x\x^TQ}Q^T:dW \\
\grad{\phi}{W}
 &= Q\BR{R\h Q^TF\x\x^TQ}Q^T \;\equiv\; G \\
}$$
Unlike the Jacobian, $G$ has the same shape as $W$ and is what you'd use for gradient descent
$$\eqalign{
\def\o{{\tt1}}
G_k &= G(W_k) \\
W_{k+\o} &= W_k - \eta_k\,G_k \\
k &= k+\o \\
}$$
$\sf NB\!:\:$ The Frobenius product $(:)$ was used in the gradient calculation
$$A:B = I:\LR{A^TB} = \trace{A^TB}$$
It commutes with the Hadamard product and is indispensable for such calculations.

Comment: Why there is no $dQ$ term exists in the formula? Since $Q$ depends on $W$ I would imagine it should show up.

Comment: @obareey  The Daleckii-Krein Theorem is weird but true, and it says there is no such contribution from $dQ.\;$

Comment: As I understand from Theorem 2.10 in this source (https://eprints.maths.manchester.ac.uk/2466/1/covered/MIMS_ep2016_24.pdf#page26) it gives the derivative of $f(X)$ at $X=W$. I was wondering how one can calculate the derivative when $W$ as a parameter, but it turns out you need to know the “point” at which you take the derivative to be able to do the calculation.

Answer (score 0):

The expansion continues by commutators $$e^A e^W  = e^{A + W  + \sum_n  c_n \ e^{ n-\text{fold symmetrized commutators}[A,B]}},$$
the so called [Baker-Cambell-Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't know nothing regarding commutator. I will take a look. But just as an update, the matrices are of the following type: A is a diagonal matrix and W is a symmetric matrix with zeros in the diagonal (so, off diagonal and symmetric)